# Replace single quote with double quote inside quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I am not that familiar with regex and tried to come up with an expression to solve the following problem:

Suppose there is text like this

```
'Foo's Bar' is a nice place in 'Seattle'
```

There is an upstream service I call that relies on the OData spec, which requires single quotes to be escaped when they are not used to terminate a statement. I am looking to transform the above text to:

```
'Foo''s Bar' is a nice place in 'Seattle'
```

I cannot rely on the user to sanitize their input. How would I solve this with regex? The pattern I found (somewhere here on SO) `('[^']*)'s([^']*')` cannot be used reliably as the assumption is that there is an `s` in the text, the text may very well be `'Foo' Bar'` and should be transformed to `'Foo'' Bar'`.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with regular expressions but I think this should do it: `('[^']*)'([^']*')` all you need is to remove the `s`...

Comment: i think there is no way to know which are the to be quoted ones. consider double quotes for statements before processing (`$'\042'`)

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(text, @"\b'\b", "''")`